# hook_preprocess_node() execution order

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

If I have two modules, each has implemented its preprocess_node hook. Then which one will be called first ? Is there anyway to enforce the order in which it would be called ?

```
module1_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  $vars['submitted'] = "test1";
}

module2_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  $vars['submitted'] = "test2";
}
```

I wonder which would be the result... test1, or test2.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All hooks in Drupal are fired in module-weight order. By default, all module's have a weight of zero, so if you want to control the exact order they fire in, you need to change something in the database.

[How to Update a Module's Weight](http://drupal.org/node/110238)

If you look at the API docs for [module_list()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/module_list/6), ties break in alphabetical order of the filename of the .module file.

Answer (score 2):

If the modules didn't change their weight in the table `system`, then the result will be `test2`.

The first module invoked is the one with a lighter weight; when two modules have the same weight, they are sorted by alphabetical ascending order.
This is valid for every invoked hook.